# ggplot2 displays columns that are not in the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have problems with a ggplot, pretty straighforward i thought, but somehow it displays data that is not there, how can i get rid of the empty space where it seems to display columns for x = 2 and 5

```
Data <- structure(list(DQRNiveau = c(0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8),
              Group = c("Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", "Beta", "Beta", "Beta", "Beta", "Beta", "Beta", "Beta"),
              n_Count = c(2L, 4L, 11L, 77L, 45L, 102L, 13L, 2L, 4L, 16L, 103L, 58L, 109L, 13L)),
              .Names = c("DQRNiveau", "Group", "n_Count"), row.names = c(NA, -14L),
              class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


ggplot(data = Data, aes(DQRNiveau, y = n_Count, fill = Group)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(1))  +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(Data$DQRNiveau))
```

[image]

Comment: You’ve asked for a continuous scale but discontinuities at 2 and 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `DQRNiveau` is numeric, it creates spaces. If you convert it to character it should work alright because it treats it as a categorical variable.

```
ggplot(data = Data, aes(as.character(DQRNiveau), y = n_Count, fill = Group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(1)) + 
  xlab('DQRNiveau')
```

[image]